# Secure login, registration and user data preservation (PHP & MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, security

I need to create a simple web based service which needs a few users who interact with MySQL database. I'm quite new with information security, so I'm just thinking of creating a table with username, password and so on.

Login would be executed by simple query like

```
SELECT username, password FROM User WHERE username=usernameGiven 
 AND password=passwordGiven
```

and registration by simple `INSERT INTO` query. How secure is this? The security doesn't have to be bulletproof because data inside the service isn't all that sensitive.

Is this a good practice, or could anyone give a few good tips to make it more secure with moderate effort?

Comment: Please searh on Google first? You can use SSL certificates to secure too. Rest depends on your way of coding .Try and post code here so that we can improve it further. You can check https://github.com/elpeyotl/Secure-login-and-registration-form

Comment: In general, questions about designing secure systems are best asked on [security.se]. I don't understand what the question is here though, it looks like you haven't analyzed your system enough to figure out what the threats and requirements are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use a password encryption like md5
- Use a password salt in your database and in your php application
- Don't grant all previllege to mysql user.
- Always query the database with escaped params
- Avoid mysql_* functions
- Take care of xss attack

I think these are the basic security a web application should have. Read each in detail by googling. Some other method also will be there but these are the things I know.

Comment: `md5` is not an encryption algorithm, and besides that it is not recommended anymore for hashing.

Comment: it is not recommended anymore for hashing? why?

Comment: There are several issues, for instance a collision attack. You can find a lot on the internet about it, but the main reason is that there are better options available at no cost in usage, but great advantage in security. Of those the `SHA` family is the most widely known I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store the password but some function f of the password x where given y it is hard to find any x with f (x)=y

Comment: Is this a common practice?

Comment: Yes, this is essential. Look up 'hashing' and 'salting' - better yet, use a ready-made library that does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should first encrypt the password (you can use one of the one way encryption algorithms like md5, sha, ...), then save the encrypted password in the database. In order to check the username and password you can use the same way, to encrypt the entered password, and compare it with the one in the database.

To add more protection you should use Captcha in the login page in order to protect the form against Brut-force attacks (trying common passwords).